# Dict with same keys names

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, object, dictionary

I need a dictionary that has two keys with the same name, but different values. One way I tried to do this is by creating a class where I would put the each key name of my dictionary, so that they would be different objects:

```
names = ["1", "1"]
values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
dict = {}

class Sets(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

for i in range(len(names)):
    dict[Sets(names[i])] = values[i]

print dict
```

The result I was expecting was:

```
{"1": [1, 2, 3], "1": [4, 5, 6]}
```

But instead it was:

```
{"1": [4, 5, 6]}
```

[EDIT]
So I discovered that keys in a dictionary are meant to be unique, having two keys with the same name is a incorrect use of dictionary. So I need to rethink my problem and use other methods avaliable in Python.

Comment: You would be using a wrong tool for a problem. Dictionary key are useful for uniqueness. :|. Better explain what exactly is your input and output requirement with a real example.

Comment: "I need a dictionary that has two keys with the same name, but different values." Why do you think you need this? I suggest you either map the unique keys to lists of values (lists of lists in your case) or just use a list of tuples (key, value)

Comment: Dictionaries always have **unique** keys. You cannot do what you want to do with a dictionary. Perhaps you are trying to solve the wrong problem, why do you think you need this?

Comment: Why do you *need* it? how are you going to use it? what do you expect to be the value of `dict["1"]`? If you explain the context, we can suggest a good approach. (also, don't name your variable `dict`)

Comment: Also, your workaround works fine.

Comment: @Vincent The workaround does not work. How would you retrieve a value this way? Either you create a new `Sets`, but this will have a different hash (the reason it seems to work in the first place), or you iterate all the keys and compare the `name`, but then you can just as well use a list of tuples.

Comment: Why don't use just used a paired tuple instead, for example: `[(1, 'valueA'), (2, 'valueB')]`

Comment: Ok people, sorry for my misunderstood. Initially I had different key names for different pictures of me "arthur.jpg". I extracted the pixels values for each picture, then I arranged them in my dictionary where the key would be the picture name in alphabetical and numerical order(ex:"arthur1.jpg","arthur2.jpg"...) and its values are the pixels values for each of them. I am trying to make a dataset for my face recognition, but for that the keys names for different "arthur.jpg" need all to be labeled into a single variable or name (in this case, "1").

Comment: Also you definitely did not search before you posted because this same question has come up like 3 times in the last 2 days.

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do is not possible with dictionaries. In fact, it is contrary to the whole *idea* behind dictionaries.

Also, your `Sets` class won't help you, as it effectively gives each name a new (sort of random) hash code, making it difficult to retrieve items from the dictionary, other than checking *all* the items, which defeats the purpose of the dict. You can not do `dict.get(Sets(some_name))`, as this will create a *new* `Sets` object, having a *different* hash code than the one already in the dictionary!

What you can do instead is:

1. Just create a list of `(name, value)` pairs, or

   ```
   pairs = zip(names, values) # or list(zip(...)) in Python 3
   ```
2. create a dictionary mapping names to lists of values.

   ```
   dictionary = {}
   for n, v in zip(names, values):
       dictionary.setdefault(n, []).append(v)
   ```

The first approach, using lists of tuples, will have linear lookup time (you basically have to check all the entries), but the second one, a dict mapping to lists, is as close as you can get to "multi-key-dicts" and should serve your purposes well. To access the values per key, do this:

```
for key, values in dictionary.iteritems():
    for value in values:
        print key, value
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of wanting multiple keys with the same name, could you getting away of having multiple values per each key?

```
names = [1]
values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

dict = {}

for i in names:
    dict[i] = values

for k,v in dict.items():
    for v in dict[k]:
        print("key: {} :: v: {}".format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
key: 1 :: v: [1, 2, 3]
key: 1 :: v: [4, 5, 6]
```

Then you would access each value like this (or in a loop):

```
print("Key 1 value 1: {}".format(dict[1][0]))
print("Key 1 value 2: {}".format(dict[1][1]))
```