# How to append and update the data to the same key in dictionary using python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to append and update the data in the dictionary. As a process, I was using the for loop to update the values in the dictionary. However, the **key** is the same but the **values** are different.

```
dict = 
dict[key1] = ['value1',value2,value3]
dict.update({key1:[value4,value5,value6]})
```

I need to update the data to the same key to a dictionary in different line. The following is the expected output:
print(dict)

```
{'key1':['value1','value2','value3'],
 'key1':['value4','value5','value6']}
```

can someone help to fix the issue?

Comment: in your first line `dict =` should be `dict= dict()` or `dict= {}` and you should not name your variable 'dict' because `dict` is a type

Comment: name it dicti or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally wrong, the whole point of dictionary's is to have **different** key's and to assign them the same or different values, dictionary's are for storing values based on ***different*** keys, so you can access them later. For more information click on this [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648813/dict-with-same-keys-names)

Comment: Thank you @shape. I have recreated my dictionary with different keys

Comment: Happy to help :)